# Spring Data and MongoDB repository - how to create an update query?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following jpa repository:

```
   @Query("UPDATE PlayerAccount pa SET pa.password = ?3 WHERE pa.id = ?1 AND pa.password = ?2")
   @Modifying
   public int updatePasswordWithValidation(Long playerAccountId, String oldPasswordDB, String encodePassword);
```

Now, i would like to implement a similar update query for a mongoDB repository:

```
@Query("update( { _id: ObjectId(' $1 ') }, { $set: { messageStatus: $2} })")
```

But it doesn't work. any references to how a customized mongo repository update looks like?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MongoDB query language is a query-only language. Thus, there's no such thing as an update query. If you need to executed dedicated updates with a Spring Data repository on top of MongoDB, you need a custom implementation method.

```
// Interface for custom functionality
interface SomeCustomRepository {
  void updateMethod(…);
}

// Custom implementation
class FooRepositoryImpl implements SomeCustomRepository {

  public void updateMethod(…) {
    mongoTemplate.update(…);
  }
}

// Core repository declaration combining CRUD functionality and custom stuff
interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, ObjectId>, SomeCustomRepository {
  …
}
```

This approach is also described in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#repositories.single-repository-behavior).

Comment: Hey Oliver, link is 404

Comment: @Madbreaks this is update for specific release: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior

Answer (score -1):

If you just pass the previously auto-created _id of the Object with the updated object values, MongoDB 'Update's rather than 'Create' a new instance.