# Partial Update query in spring boot throws "BsonInvalidOperationException"

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am working on spring boot and perform CRUD operations on my mongoDB.

my object looks like

```
@Entity
@Document(collection = "customers")
public class Customer {

  @Id String _id;
  String mane;
  String isActive;

}
```

and the repository

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

  @Modifying
  @Query("update Customer r set r.isActive = :status where r.id = :id")
  int update(@Param(value = "id") String id, @Param(value = "status") String status);
}
```

and when I call my service

```
@Autowired private CustomerRepository repo;

  public void updateStatus(String id, String status) {
    repo.update(id, status);
  }
```

it throws error

```
BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING.
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020046/custom-method-for-update-query-with-spring-data-mongorepository) might help you.

Comment: I didn't find the `@Modifying` annotation definition in the Spring Data MongoDB API. Also, see this similar SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849916/spring-data-and-mongodb-repository-how-to-create-an-update-query